# A question of mine has apparently vanished

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions

It was titled something like: 3-d representation of CQHRL(5). If I deleted this, it was not intentional. Can someone restore this question? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527143/3-d-representation-of-cqhrl-5). 10k users can see it, but I think the OP can see it too? I've forgotten. It seems that the SE software automatically deleted it roughly a month after it was asked. I know that questions with no upvotes and no answers are deleted eventually - I conjecture that this happened to your question.

Comment: As @mixedmath mentions, the question was automatically deleted by the [Community user](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19739/214632) (_i.e._, the system) two days ago.  Some of the relevant facts about this can be found in [this MSO answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/214632).  In particular, the question was negatively scored, unlocked, had no answers, and was posted more than 30 days ago.

Comment: I've restored it, but now I see that it in fact had a score of -1, so now I'm much more confident in my supposition that the SE software removed it.

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Comment: @mixedmath I'm pretty sure that it requires strictly negative score for questions to be deleted.